# having trouble controlling the width of tds in Internet Explorer 7 and 8

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I set the width using:

```
style="width: 200px"
```

When the browser window is narrow, the td is the correct width. When I make the window wide, the td expands wider than what I set it to. Any ideas?

Comment: please post your entire table, or at least a simplified sample reproducing your problem.

Comment: Darko Z, I will, but part of the problem it's a tables layout (which I didn't create and can't change), and it's a mess of nested tables. When I simplify it, I think the problem goes away. So I'm looking for any quick, low-hanging fruit suggestions before I really roll up my sleeves.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that you have specified a width on the actual table and the cells within your table aren't equal to the width of the table.  Thus internet explorer, and I would suspect most other browsers, have to compensate and widen all the cells, including your fixed width one.

Either remove the width specification from your table or change one of the cells in your table to something more flexible like a width="10%".

However, I this is not likely to be a good approach, though it might get you on the right track.  @Darko Z is right, we need some more code.

Comment: Thanks David, enough to jostle my brain a bit and maybe help me find a different angle of attack.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [colgroups](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.4).

Also, you can try playing with other style attributes like dysplay, etc. 
I believe if you give a fixed width to each column, you have to set a fixed width to the table element.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not my code, it's a header that's included in a script tag and rendered with document.write, so I can't change the structure very easily.

Answer (score 0):

Almost for sure, you are out of luck here.

Browser treats bunch of nested autofit tables as one big complex thing. It tries to find optimal layout taking into account cell contents (minimum and maximum) width and various settings, like the one you have. None of the settings is considered set in stone.

So, if you have simple and non-contradictory requirements, they will be honored. Otherwise, all bets are off.

Comment: Thanks, buti-oxa. That will help me feel better about myself when I give up :) Fortunately the bug this is causing is a fairly minor cosmetic one.